# does Theano's symbolic matrix inverse "know" about structured matrices?

Tags: theano

In my application I am computing the inverse of a block tridiagonal matrix A - will Theano's matrix inverse account for that structure (by using a more efficient matrix inverse algorithm)?

Further, I only need the diagonal and first off diagonal blocks of the resulting inverse matrix. Is there a way of preventing Theano from computing the remaining blocks?

Generally, I'm curious whether it would be worth implementing a forward/backward block tridagonal matrix inverse algorithm myself.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2015 Theano matrix inverse function won't do it directly:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nlinalg.html#theano.tensor.nlinalg.MatrixInverse

Theano do not have many optimization and function related to that type of methods. It partially wrap what is under numpy.linalg (most of it) and some of scipy.linalg:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/slinalg.html

So you are better in the short term to do it with numpy/scipy directly.

If you want to add those feature to Theano, this can be done. But it need someone with the time and willingness to do it.